# thread safety when using parse() with Java SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, thread-safety, simpledateformat

I try my best to study source code to find out why it's not thread safe for parse() in SimpleDateFormat. But I still have no idea that where to destroy the race condition

Comment: Are you interested as an intellectual exercise in mastering concurrency programming? Or looking for a practical solution in your date-time work?

Answer (score 2):

SimpleDateFormat uses DateFormat's `calendar` field to store the current date being parsed. There is no synchronization around that field so parallel uses of the same SimpleDateFormat object may change the `calendar` values in parallel, resulting in garbled results.

PS—I perused this source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java#SimpleDateFormat.parse%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.text.ParsePosition%29

YMMV.

Comment: To add to your answer - "All of the calendar's date-time fields are cleared before parsing, and the calendar's default values of the date-time fields are used for any missing date-time information." - [`SimpleDateFormat#parse` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29)

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java#SimpleDateFormat.parse%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.text.ParsePosition%29 - Check this link. Calendar field is no longer member of DateFormat.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the race condition, create new `SimpleDateFormat` every time, and only share the format string:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "...";

private void foo() {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    ...
}
```

If (and only if) performance turns out to be an issue, you may create one `SimpleDateFormat` instance per thread. But usually creating a new instance every time you want to use it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat also uses `compiledPattern` in its parse method which is defined as:

```
transient private char[] compiledPattern;
```